# Captcha and session are not equal

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

i am trying to write captcha  firstly i wrote asp then i can take it as image .Problem is that image and session are not equal session gives one before image.i couldnt find the reason of problem.how can i fix this problem?

```
    using System;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


public partial class botdetect_captcha : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //create image
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 30);
        //create object to draw
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        //image background
        g.Clear(Color.LightBlue);

        //randomly string
        string metin = RastgeleKelime();
        //send to session for validation
        Session["gResim"] = metin;

        //create font for image
        Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", 14);

        g.DrawString(metin, font, Brushes.DarkBlue, 4, 1);


        //draw randomly three lines
        Random rnd = new Random();
        g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkSlateGray, rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30), rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkRed, rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30), rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30));
        g.DrawLine(Pens.DarkOrange, rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30), rnd.Next(0, 100), rnd.Next(0, 30));

        //make response
        bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    public string RastgeleKelime()
    {
        string kelime = "";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            kelime += ((char)rnd.Next('A', 'Z')).ToString();
        }
        return kelime;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a `PostBack` Issue.. also I would suggest storing the intialized Session["gResim"];  value in the `Global.asax file and then assigning it properly as well as getting rid of the Session.Clear() method probably not necessary what happens when you step through the code.. also translate your comments into `English`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would "fix it" by taking the following steps:

Move the image creation to a custom handler. When image is created, store unique value in session or some other location.

Add image tag, set the source to the handler.

Add input control for user to enter a response

Submit response to server

Server compares response to unique value.

Handle response.